# What is the most efficient way to process rows in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am teaching myself basic and intermediate SQL concepts for a project I am working on.

I have a lot of data that needs to undergo processing so it can be presented in different ways. Right now I am using scalar functions calls in my select statement to process the data.

A simple example, lets say I have an attribute in my table called fun as data type int. I want to process my table so that all rows with fun < 10 are 'foo' and all rows with fun > 10 are 'faa'.

So I write an SQL function something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fooORfaa
(
    @fun AS int
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(3)
AS
BEGIN
     IF (@fun < 10)
         RETURN 'foo'
     RETURN 'faa' 
END
```

Then I use my function in something like this select statement

```
select dbo.fooORfaa([mytable].[fun]) AS 'blah'
from mytable
```

This example is trivial, but in my real code I need perform some fairly involved logic against one or more columns, and I am selecting sub results from procedures and joining tables together and other things you need to do in a data base.

I have to process lots of records in a reasonable time span. Is this method an efficient way to tackle this problem? Is there another technique I should be using instead?

Comment: if the fields underlying your `fooORfaa` function are relatively unchanging, and/or the calculations you're doing are "heavy" or "expensive", then you'd probably be better off saving them in extra fields so you don't waste a ton of cpu redoing all the calculations every time you work with the table. a few appropriate triggers can keep the table up-to-date on the (hopefully) rare occasions the values do get changed.

Comment: Use store Store procedure

Comment: While unintuitive, table-valued functions are often more efficient than scalar-valued functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, you need a CASE construct.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN T.fun < 10 THEN 'foo'
    ELSE 'faa'
  END foo_faa
FROM
  myTable T
```

Always try to use set-based operations. User-defined functions will (mostly) kill your performance, and should be a last resort.

[See: CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think I can apply that to most of my transformations. One more question though, how do I prevent my select statements from exploding? One nice side effect of the scalar functions was much more readable code. I could nest a bunch of select statements using stored procedure, but I think that might have an adverse effect on performance as well.

Comment: You really can't. There's no free lunch on this. Sometimes, you can put a few things in a view, but then you end up with a spaghetti of views referencing views, and it becomes hard for the query optimizer to make efficient plans as it tries to fold views together. So, living with SQL is to live with this. This is not like c# or other procedural languages. Many SQL dialects have procedural extensions, such as UDFs, but those are normally kept for edge cases or transactional applications. Retrievals like what you are doing are almost always best served like this.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will just get really fussy over my indentations instead. Much appreciated.

Comment: Excellent. Indentations become second nature in short order. I cannot stand giant stored procedures written on three lines of inscrutable, lower-case code. It's not maintainable, even by the original authors, much less readable.